# How to extend classes and controllers in PrestaShop 1.7?

Tags: prestashop

I want to extend some core classes and controllers via a module but I don't know how. I can do it with overrides but according to the developers this isn't a good way:

> The legacy architecture can still be overridden, though. But in
>   general, we advise against overriding code. **It is better to extend it.**

But how can I extend it? Is there any code example?

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

In prestashop docs you can see the [override](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors).

Put ur class in /modules/my_module/override/classes 
or controller /modules/my_module/override/controllers/{front or admin}

I use it on my modules.

An example of my module, overriding a  frontcontroller function:

```
    <?php

class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    protected function smartyOutputContent($content)
    {
        if (version_compare(_PS_VERSION_, '1.7', '<')) {
            //do something
        } else {
            parent::smartyOutputContent($content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to submit the module to the PrestaShop Marketplace. So I'm not allowed to use any override. :(

Comment: Isn't this the old way of overwriting? All files in modules/xx/override will be installed to the override dir. And or only works for legacy files. If I need to"override" a ps file from the symfony structure I need to "extend" but I honestly do not know how.